# Descargar mediante la etiqueta a no funciona

Tags: html, reactjs, download

Quiero descargar una imagen mediante la etiqueta `<a></a>` pero este no resulta, ya que cuando le doy click, simplemente de dirige a la imagen y no lo descarga, segun tento entendido para hacer la descarga es:

```
<a className="btn btn-primary" href={ele.url} download={ele.nombre}>
    <i className="bi bi-cloud-arrow-down"></i>
</a>
```

Estoy usando react pero no funciona, no se si estoy haciendo algo mal o no?

Comment: El atributo `download` no funciona si la URL no pertenece al mismo dominio, es ese tu caso? Es decir si el link aparece en la pagina `a.com`, pero el link apunta a `b.com` el atributo no funcionará

Comment: Ahhhh ya, en este caso no, este apunta a otro dominio

Comment: Por eso... Si apunta a otro dominio no va a funcionartw

Comment: Gracias, eso si no lo sabia